# Is it possible to extend the DatePicker control

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a UWP app that has many Date entry fields and I currently use the DatePicker to provide the three spinners for day, month and year. In most cases this works well for my users, but where the field is a date of birth it's causing some issues for the users. They are complaining about having to scroll back through the years, in some cases many of them. Is there a way to extend or override the spinner for the year to change the behaviour of the arrow buttons to skip forward or backward ten at a time?

I've looked at using the CalendarView but I think this introduces UX issues when selecting the actual day, I feel it's more suited for mouse use rather than touch.

Any help or pointers much appreciated

Comment: I am not quite sure, but can't you set a maximum date? So you could remove "senseless" or  not allowed birth dates, e.g. if the user must be of legal age

Comment: @Creepin The maxdate is being used to prevent future dates being entered, but the app needs to be able to record any DoB, the main issue arises for elderly people where the year has to be scrolled several times.

Comment: Yes, yes, I see. Just in case ages lower than legal age are not valid, you could use the MaxDate to remove thoses dates and elderly people don't have to scroll this much. But if all birth dates are valid, then of course, this is no solution